# Hibernate Restrictions.or

Tags: hibernate, restriction

I wonder why the Restrictions.or only can accept 2 parameter.

I Need to do something like below.

```
(A and B) or (C and D) or ( E and F ) or (G and H) or ...
```

Any idea can achieve this?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Per the [API Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#or%28org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion...%29), the `.or(...)` method is overloaded.  The one you reference and another that takes an array o

> public static Disjunction or(Criterion... predicates)